# Force one JFrame to always be on top of another

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, always-on-top, modality

I want to have a JFrame that is always on top of another 'parent' frame but *not* always on top of everything

I have attempted to use:

1. `JInternalFrame` -- doesn't work because I have to use JDesktopPane which is unnaceptable because the parent frame relies on a Border layout.
2. `JFrame` with `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` -- doesn't work because I only want it to be on top of its parent frame

I'm imagining a method like `setAlwaysOnTopOf(JFrame parent)`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to have a JFrame that is always on top of another 'parent' frame

Applications should only contain a single JFrame. If you need a child window then use a (modal?) `JDialog` and specify the frame as the parent.

Comment: Thank you! A _non_-modal dialog ended up being exactly what I needed! For confused people like me, a missing piece to making the dialog is `new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this));`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584646/how-to-hide-jdialog-from-japplet-when-user-switch-browser-tab

Answer (score 0):

that depends on which container you are using...
bind your jFrame to the container..
try with add method..